# Error of spawn vue-cli-service ENOENT after updating vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

My vue project started throwing errors last night. At first I thought it was some sort of node issue because my project wasn't fully loading, which wasn't an issue before and I kept getting an audit issue about my cli plugin. I update node to the latest version and it uploaded fully once, then later it stopped loading and showing anything on the screen. This morning, I tried loading it through the vue cli instead of the terminal and noticed they had updated the vue cli plugin. I updated my vue cli plugin and tried to build my project but now I'm getting this error

"spawn vue-cli-service ENOENT"

can anyone help me with this error and what to do to get my vue project back up and running? Everything was up and running fine before this. Not really sure what is going on. I also have the following plugins running on my project, not sure if that may be impacting anything: vuetify, axios, vuex, vue router, and I have firebase and firestore, as well.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check out [this vue-cli GitHub Issue thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2096) with the same error. It looks like [they solved it](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2096#issuecomment-469937147) by deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install`.

Comment: Yeah, I did that last night and it worked. Just tried again after your comment and a no go. I just tried again but chose the Vue 3 preview and it's working fine now...still not sure what is causing this issue but even after I had deleted node_modules, node, reinstalled node and reinstalled node into my project, it was throwing other errors...so I''m going to see how this works. Maybe it's the new cli causing the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following link. It worked for me right away.

https://programmerah.com/solution-of-serve-with-message-spawn-vue-cli-service-enoent-395/

I ran all this in Windows shell

1. in CMD into the project directory (this is very important!!)
2. execute NPM install
3. re-import in the visualization panel. (I just ran "vue ui")

Prior to doing this I had installed node using windows installer and then the following from the powershell

1. npm update -g @vue/cli
2. npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global

restart if you need to, go to the project directory in powershell and "vue ui" without quotes and it worked after that. I was able to compile and run the project without any issues. Once the task is built, you may open a new tab and goto localhost:8080

best of luck! (it was a witch-hunt for me)